# What are the consequences of disabling HID-compliant devices?

Tags: windows-10, hid

I'm attempting to improve the frame-rate for a PC game called Condemned. My machine exceeds the recommended requirements described back in 2006. The machine is, however, running Windows 10.

Many [forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/4720/discussions/0/864950181823798471/) are recommending that I disable "HID-Compliant Devices":

> To get the best performance, you are going to want to disable all "HID-Compliant Device", you should not need to disable ANYTHING else.

I can't find any reasoning behind this method.

Inspecting the Properties of these devices via Device Manager doesn't tell me much about them. There are three types of HID-compliant devices on my machine:

1. consumer control device (4 instances)
2. system controller       (2 instances)
3. vendor-defined device   (6 instances)

I have no idea what functionality is provided through these. I'm worried that I'll disable my keyboard or mouse if I disable these entries.

Update: Condemned will randomly have dramatically sharp drops in fps. Dropping from ~180 to 8. Unplugging the keyboard and mouse seems to restore the normal frame-rate.

Also, all but one of the HID-Compliant devices vanish once I disconnect them from my KVM: [image]

Switching from my computer to another via the KVM's switches makes for a quick remedy.

Comment: I can't imagine any reason that would help, but I'm not a high-performance expert.

Comment: Yes; you likely will disable your keyboard and mouse, and the suggestion, won't result in higher fps

Comment: I'm beginning to think there may be a connection as I noted in my update

Comment: You never mentioned that you were using a **KVM Switch** before, KVM is something comcpletely different, please keep that in mind. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch

Comment: I didn't think I'd need to distinguish the two.

Answer (score 1):

I have found disabling HID does indeed allow FEAR and games that seem to be sensitive to POLLING of HID devices to run well.

FEAR would run ~ 25 FPS and go to over 200 FPS with HID devices disables with a 1070ti video card and AMD Ryzen 2600X CPU, for instance.

Oddly, my keyboard, mouse and sound ALL function 100% normally with the HID devices disabled. I rebooted to see if maybe a re-set is needed, but no, everything works the "same" as I use the PC after a re boot.

If I ENABLE the HID devices, FEAR FPS collapses to unplayable. SO I've kept them disabled while I play this game, and re-enable them later on when I'm finished.

My experience suggests that disabling HID devices to trouble shoot an odd older game MIGHT be a solution to more consistent FPS elsewhere, and that mouse / keyboard function, at least on my ASRock X470 Taichi W10 system, still work fine.

Report of the HID device POLLING frequency slowly bringing FPS down in certain older games seem to be the "answer". Stopping the polling by disabling the device drivers fixes it...I'm told. But, it works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself. However from reading forums, this is a very common recommendation, and does apparently make a big difference. Apparently it shouldn't actually stop the devices from working, but may reduce some additional functionality.

Comment: Ah, so this will just remove features outside mouse clicks and key presses

Comment: @VitaminYes That would be my guess. These additional features would likely include customised buttons etc. The mouse/keyboard I expect would still function as PS/2 compatible devices.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same in order to play the game 'Fear'. However, i lost no additional functionality of the multimedia buttons of my keyboard, or mouse, or my Speakers. This is the only features it disables. Make sure to only disable the 'HID-compliant device' devices. No other HID devices.

More details on HID [here](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/what-is-the-human-interface-device-access-hidserv-service/).

Btw, if it still doesn't work for you disable the in-game Vsync. You can instead select the fast sync option from the Nvidia Profile Inspector application after you select the app / game you want and then setting the VSync option to FastSync.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently having issues with long loading times for Minecraft Forge (a modded Minecraft instance) and apparently LWJGL (Light Weight Java Games Library) was hanging on this exact same issue, up to 40 seconds(!!). Disabling the HID-compliant devices has bizarrely changed none of my functionality for any of my peripherals, yet has made loading near-instantaneous.

Bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with my mouse. Mouse cursor was moving on its own. After long investigation I noticed I have 3 HID-compliant mouse devices ”installed”. I tested to disable one by one and finally I found which of them caused the problem. So I kept 1 of those 3 HID mouse devices disabled, and voilaaaa - my mouse cursor is normal now. This weird problem came either after a Windows update or after I upgraded my graphic card... I don't know what that 3rd mystical HID-compliant mouse is. But I don't care, I will keep it disabled as long as my mouse works.

Answer (score 0):

nothing wrong when we disable HID ,but Pcie is another story ,I using windows iso from Tc & AXE build [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYhRW.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

HID = Human Interface Device (Usually used to refer to peripherals such as keyboards and mice)

I guess from that you can tell that HID Compliant Devices are most likely going to be some input devices or others you have connected to your computer. Disabling them all would probably lead your HID's to stop working, because you know... you disabled them. Are you sure this wasn't just some troll post that recommended you to do this?

Judging by the setup in device manager, I imagine "HID Compliant Device" is some sort of slot, so basically if you plug in another HID one of these slots will be filled to activate that device. It could also be left-over generic HID drivers for devices you have once upon a time plugged into your computer but are not currently plugged in (for faster hot-plugging). This could also actually be active drivers for your current devices or some of their components, I don't know because information about this on the internet seems lacking. But either way, I don't see why this would have any positive effects for anything. Definitely sounds like a shady deal to me, but please tell me how it goes if you try. Worst case, your Keyboard and mouse will stop working, what do you have to lose?

Comment: The advice was not directed at me, but multiple users across different sites. Also, I believe windows will hide or "ghost" unplugged devices and not insert the "HID-compliant" string in front of them.

Comment: @VitaminYes might be, this seems awful poorly documented after all.

Comment: Ghosted/hidden devices: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/remove-uninstall-hiddenghosted-devices/

Comment: @VitaminYes I meant HID Compliant Devices being poorly documented. And that isn't documentation, it's a "windows tip" but I get what you mean, it's probably true although it doesn't seem to apply 100% of the time (for example my device manager is displaying a Corsair input device despite none being connected to the computer at the moment, my corsair keyboard is actually connected to a different computer but I tested it in the past on this computer)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that as a supplement to my first comment. Not sure if Microsoft has any KB's on it